# need to recreate sp_send_dbmail in msdb system procedure folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbmail

We have a SQL Server 2008 system.

Somehow the sp_send_dbmail sproc got deleted from msdb.

When I recreate the sproc, it does not get put in the system folder and gets put in the general sproc folder of msdb.

Anyone know how to move the sproc or create it in the correct directory?

Comment: I have to do this for one of our servers, did you have any luck recreating it? I am thinking I'm just going to script the procedure from a working instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undocumented stored proc `sp_MS_marksystemobject` still works on SQL Server 2008 according to the recent [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sp_MS_marksystemobject) links I found on it.